# Merge Strategy not behaving as expected

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

In build.scala I have the following:

```
mergeStrategy <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) {(old) => {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet",  "resources", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case x => old(x)
}}
```

However when I run `assembly` I see:

```
[info] Merging 'javax/servlet/resources/web-app_2_2.dtd' with strategy 'deduplicate'
```

showing that it is using the "deduplicate" strategy, not the "first" strategy.  This gives the following error:

```
[error] {file:/home/dan/tesla/}tesla-appengine/*:assembly: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/dan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/jars/appengine-tools-sdk-1.7.3.jar:javax/servlet/resources/web-app_2_2.dtd
[error] /home/dan/.ivy2/cache/javax.servlet/servlet-api/jars/servlet-api-2.5.jar:javax/servlet/resources/web-app_2_2.dtd
```

Answer (score 1):

I had not applied this setting in the proper scope.  I needed to set

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= ...
```